# Is there a way to force clockwise pane rotation in iTerm2 with the shortcut keys?

Tags: terminal, iterm

I've often found that when using iTerm2, I'll have like 3 or 4 panes open in one tab.  And the shortcut keys for moving between them <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> are very useful, but unpredictable.  The reason is because "next" and "previous" panes are determined by the order in which panes had last focus.  So if I have 4 panes open in a window shape, sometimes <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> may circle around them clockwise, sometimes counterclockwise, and sometimes neither.  And I can't remember which pane had the 3rd last focus.

The problem is correctable by simply clicking on each pane in clockwise order and then using the shortcut keys, but this is kind of annoying to have to do each time.

Is there a setting where I can lock the shortcut keys into clockwise (and counterclockwise) rotation only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted about this on the Google Groups for iTerm2.  The program author has now added to the program the option to rotate clockwise.

Comment: Where is this option?

Comment: There's an option under "Preferences > Advanced > Tabs > Next Pane and Previous Pane commands use reading order, not the time of last use". It doesn't mean clockwise, but left-to-right then top-to-bottom. At least it's more deterministic :)